# My RNG value ascertains unexpected values

Tags: c++

I understand that random isn't really random, therefore `srand` with time is implemented, however it is not giving random values every time I run the program, rather the exact same value 92 and 98, or rather 2 and 8. I would like my variables `int randValPlayer = rand() % 20 + 1;` and `int randValCPU = rand() % 20 + 1;` to give random values.

I put `srand(time(0));` in my main function. I tried changing the random algorithm of my intended values.

````
class Game 
{
private:
    int playerHealth = 100;
    int cpuHealth = 100;
    int userChoice;
    int randValPlayer = rand() % 20 + 1;
    int randValCPU = rand() % 20 + 1;
public:
    int attackPlayer()
    {

        playerHealth = playerHealth - randValPlayer;
        return playerHealth;
    }
    int attackCPU()
    {

        cpuHealth = cpuHealth - randValCPU;
        return cpuHealth;
    }
    void choice() 
    {
        cout << "Input '1' to attack CPU" << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;
        if (userChoice == 1)
        {
            attackCPU();
            cout << "CPU's health reduced to " << cpuHealth << endl;
            attackPlayer();
            cout << "Player health reduced to " << playerHealth << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}gameobj;

class Foundation 
{
private:
    int userChoice;

public:
    void startProgram() 
    {
        cout << "Please input desired number: " << endl;
        cout << "1. Calculator" << endl;
        cout << "2. Equation calculator" << endl;
        cout << "3. Game" << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;
        system("cls");
        if (userChoice == 1) {
            calcobj.calcOperation();
        }
        if (userChoice == 2) {
            equationobj.equationChoice();
        }
        if (userChoice == 3) {
            gameobj.choice();
        }
    }
}foundobj;

int main()
{
    foundobj.startProgram();
    srand(time(0));
    return 0;
} ```

I expected the output to be random but the integer values are just the exact same, via 8 and 2.
````

Comment: You're seeding your random stream after the startProgram() call, so the used seed is always the same. And using rand() for initializing class members is also going to be called before you seed it.

Comment: Prefer the modern facilities in the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header over `rand()`. See also [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to take time into account - you need to seed the generator before you use it, but you're doing it as the very last thing in the program.

This program will not work even if you move `srand` first in `main`, because your global `Game` instance is created before that.

Since (mutable) global variables is a bad idea in general, this is a good opportunity for a rewrite.

I suggest something like this:

```
class Game
{
   // ...
};

class Foundation 
{
private:
    Game gameobj;
    // The other objects here...
public:
    void startProgram() 
    {
        int userChoice = 0;
        cin >> userChoice;
        // ...
        if (userChoice == 3) {
            gameobj.choice();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Foundation foundobj;
    foundobj.startProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong here:

1) You must seed the random generator by calling `srand()` *before* any calls to `rand()`. Currently you call `srand()` *after*. Thus, you will always get the same sequence of numbers from `rand()`.

2) `time(0)` is a rather bad seed. It only has a resolution of 1second, so two people both starting the program within the same second will get the same pseudo random numbers. It is also a highly guessable seed.

3) Your use of modulo in statements such as `int randValPlayer = rand() % 20 + 1;` introduces bias if the output range of `rand()` is not evenly divisible by 20.

4) `rand()` (usually) has a rather short period and limited output range. You would probably be better served by a [std::mt19937](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) combined with a [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). See the examples at the linked pages.